# How can I determine all combinations for a set of 5 numbers out of 10

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a list of 10 numbers, and I am trying to find a method to generate all combinations for sets of 5. Only the order does not matter.

Example:
I have the initial set of numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

And I would like to generate all sets of 5, such as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
...
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

However, order does not matter, so:
`[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` is equivalent to the same set as `[7, 9, 8, 10, 6]`

**Is there a way to derive the combinations of numbers in sets of 5 where order does not matter?**

**Update**:

Think of this as a lottery ticket. Only 5 numbers can be chosen out of 6 (or something like that), where order does not matter; how would generate all combinations for those tickets. (kind of a fruitless example, but its the best I could think of).

Comment: If you just want to get the job done in Python and don't care how, check out the combinations iterator in the itertools module.  For an algorithm, you might see Algorithm 7.2.1.2L in Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be exactly
$$
\binom{10}{5}
 = \frac{10!}{5!5!}
 = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6}{120}
 = 9 \cdot 4 \cdot 7
 = 252?
$$

As a generation algorithm, list them out as if you would a dictionary (rename $A = 10$ to make life simpler):

```
12345
12346
...
1234A
12356
12357
...
1235A
...
```

**UPDATE**

In Python, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/399573) on StackOverflow for complete Python example.

Comment: Well, I'm looking to actually generate the sets, not just the number of sets. But yeah, you're probably right here.

Comment: @Brett are you programming something? where are you generating them? in excel?

Comment: @Brett please see update for the generating idea

Comment: I would be doing it in Python.

Comment: you could start off with a list of your 10 numbers, and then create a set by picking randomly until the set has size 5, (or keep regenerating your original list, but keep randomly popping 5 off from a random index), do you want to generate all possibilities, or just a random one each time?

Comment: @mdave16 Am looking for all combinations.

Comment: then gt6989b's method is probably the way i would do it too, you could try asking the question on stack overflow instead, since they would be better for coding problems

Comment: @Brett see update with link for complete answer in Python

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a 5 string of sequential integers the answer is simply 6.

Comment: Not sequential, that was just my example.